# Wordpress post stay in draft (cPanel)

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

Im try to publish a post in wordpress but my post stay in draft status

before my wordpress (and all of the WordPress sites on the server) was OK !

but now all have this problem

i think this is my server config ! (cPanel)

Where is my problem? :(

My Server : cPanel - Litespeed

Sorry for my bad English :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any error while publishing your post through wp-admin panel ?

Also I will suggest you please try to disable your all plugins and check it. If you are still getting same issues then you will have to contact your hosting provider to check this.

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply  |  I said "All of the WP sites on my server have this probmel"  I create new account and install new wordpress but don't resolved | I dont have any error

Comment: Then you will have to contact your server management team, They will check your server setup and will assist you on this